# need assitance on the apigee developer portal

Tags: android, drupal, portal, apigee

I'm looking for help on the apigee developer portal as I already have experience on the Apigee edge. Please if anyone is willing to help, I  could also pay them accordingly. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. It is not a recruitment site.

Comment: Please don't expect other users here to write full code for you. Hire a freelancer for that job. Here users volunteer to help other users when they are stuck on a specific programming related problem.